# Create constraints and indexes on table using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

Can we create constraints and indexes on a table, using SSIS package? If so, how can we do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like this one could be answered with google.com... SSIS can execute almost any sql script.

Comment: I dont see any advantage using sql script in SSIS. We can do that in your sp/sqlJob or directly in SSMS. I was looking for a hack using SSIS tools. So looking at Jacob and Eric's reply, dont see such options.

Comment: You didn't ask if there was an advantage. That question would probably be off topic here. You asked if you could do it. Which is a simple answer: Yes. And if you think that SSIS can't or shouldn't be used to execute SQL scripts, you're in for a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways. Here are two.

The most straight forward way would be to script out your constraints and indexes, then paste them into an Execute SQL Task.

The way I'd likely do it would be to put the scripts into a stored procedure, then execute the stored procedure through the Execute SQL Task.

The advantage of the second option is that you can modify the scripts in the proc without having to edit and redeploy your SSIS package.